# Find how many words start with certain letter in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to output the total of how many words start with a letter `'a'` in a list from a separate text file. I'm looking for an output such as this.

```
35 words start with a letter 'a'.
```

However, i'm outputting all the words that start with an `'a'` instead of the total with my current code. Should I be using something other than a for loop?

So far, this is what I have attempted:

```
wordsFile = open("words.txt", 'r')
words = wordsFile.read()
wordsFile.close()
wordList = words.split()

print("Words:",len(wordList)) # prints number of words in the file.

a_words = 0

for a_words in wordList:
    if a_words[0]=='a':
        print(a_words, "start with the letter 'a'.")
```

The output I'm getting thus far:

```
Words: 334
abate start with the letter 'a'.
aberrant start with the letter 'a'.
abeyance start with the letter 'a'.
```

and so on.

Comment: _However, i'm outputting all the words that start with an 'a'_  That's because in your `for` loop, you have a `print` statement.  If you don't want to print the words, then... don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `a_words` as the value of the word in each iteration and missing a counter. If we change the for loop to have `words` as the value and reserved `a_words` for the counter, we can increment the counter each time the criteria is passed. You could change `a_words` to `wordCount` or something generic to make it more portable and friendly for other letters.

```
a_words = 0

for words in wordList:
    if words[0]=='a':
        a_words += 1

print(a_words, "start with the letter 'a'.")
```

Comment: This is doing exactly that: summing the occurrences of words starting with letter 'a'.  What more do you want?  There is nothing more efficient than this simple linear solution.  In fact, any other method introduces added overhead (certainly not significant enough to affect performance, but still unnecessary).  Moreover, I prefer this over Jim's single line solution on the basis that it seems you need a better understanding of basic looping and general software development problem solving.

Comment: This does output the total on one line. If you take your `print` statement out of the for loop, then it will only print the total after the execution of the loop is complete.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace this with a `sum` call in which you feed `1` for every word in `wordList` that starts with `a`:

```
print(sum(1 for w in wordList if w.startswith('a')), 'start with the letter "a"')
```

This can be further trimmed down if you use the boolean values returned by `startswith` instead, since `True` is treated as `1` in these contexts the effect is the same:

```
print(sum(w.startswith('a') for w in a), 'start with the letter "a"')
```

With your current approach, you're not summing anything, you're simply printing any word that matches. In addition, you're re-naming `a_word` from an `int` to the contents of the list as you iterate through it.

Also, instead of using `a_word[0]` to check for the first character, you could use `startswith(character)` which has the same effect and is a bit more readable.

Comment: As great as this is, it's hiding the fundamental details which seemingly the OP truly needs a better understanding of.

Comment: @JSF Indeed, but this isn't solely about the OP, it's about anyone who might bump into this. I gave a general solution and a small explanation of his mistake; if OP needs fundamentals he should go to `docs.python.org` and not StackOverflow :P

Comment: But alas, here he is. Him and those like him; they aren't going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`sum(generator)` is a way to go, but for completeness sake, you may want to do it with list comprehension (maybe if it's slightly more readable or you want to do something with words starting with *a* etc.).

```
words_starting_with_a = [word for word in word_list if word.startswith('a')]
```

After that you may use `len` built-in to retrieve length of your new list.

```
print(len(words_starting_with_a), "words start with a letter 'a'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple alternative solution using `re.findall` function(without splitting text and `for` loop):

```
import re
...
words = wordsFile.read()
...
total = len(re.findall(r'\ba\w+?\b', words))
print('Total number of words that start with a letter "a" : ', total)
```